# How does the mathematical definition of drag reduce to Stokes or form drag?

Tags: drag, navier-stokes

I know that for the flow of flow of a Navier-Stokes fluid in a domain, once the velocity $\mathbf{v}$ and pressure p are known, the drag over a solid object with boundary $\partial R$ is given by taking the component along the flow of the integral
$$ Drag = \int_{\partial R} (-p\hat{n} + \mu (\nabla \mathbf{v} + \nabla \mathbf{v}^T)\hat{n} ) da$$

However, I also read that for creeping or slow flow,
$$Drag = -b\mathbf{v}$$ This can be derived for drag on a sphere from the general formula.

Hwever, the form drag is
$$Drag = 0.5 \; \rho\; A \; C_D ||\mathbf{v}||^2$$

Is it possible to show that the general mathematical equation for the drag reduces to the square of the velocity as stated above ?

*EDIT*: Thanks for pointing out the missing factor of area. Corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**short version:** No, there is no way to show that the general integral equation for the drag reduces directly to the square of the velocity because for different flow regimes, different velocity and pressure distributions exist.

**long version:** The quadratic drag equation is actually given by:
$$F_d=C_d\frac{1}{2}\rho||\mathbf{v}||^2A$$
where $A$ is usually the orthographic projected area (so a circle in case of a sphere, a square in case of a cube, etc.). This equation can be viewed as a dimensional analysis relating the drag force to the dynamic pressure ($0.5\rho||\mathbf{v}||^2$) and the area $A$ (since $p=\frac{F}{A}$) and to allow the relation to function in a wide range of flow regimes (from laminar to turbulent), a drag coefficient $C_d$ is introduced. Note: that the form may also be loosely derived from a momentum balance as suggested in the comments.

The drag coefficient in the creeping flow regime ($Re=\frac{\rho vD}{\mu}<<1$) has an analytical solution following from Stokes' drag ($F_d=6\pi\mu Rv$),

$$C_d=\frac{F_d}{\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2A}=\frac{6\pi\mu Rv}{\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2\pi R^2}=\frac{12}{Re}$$

In the turbulent regime,  there are no known solution and the value of the drag coefficient is determined experimentally or numerically. It is found to be independent of the Reynolds number with a limiting value of $O(1)$.

The use of the quadratic drag equation with the drag coefficient is the engineering approach to tying together the drag force across different regimes. It is apparently preferred to have a single relation describing the drag while the drag coefficient changes with the regimes rather than have different relations for each regime.

Comment: So, if its independent of Reynolds number, it it fair to say that it still depends on the viscosity ? Or is it independent of the viscosity too ?

Comment: *"This equation is not really a derived relation but rather the result of a dimensional analysis."* You can offer a rough derivation of its form, too: in a time $dt$ the object takes a volume $dV = A~v~dt$ of fluid and grants it a momentum proportional to $\rho~dV~v$ by "dragging it along for the ride," momentum balance says that you must experience $dp = -\alpha~\rho~v~dV = -\alpha~\rho~v^2~A~dt$, hence the force $dp/dt$ has that form for some $\alpha$. This "derivation" suggests that lower-orders than $v^2$ are possible (what if it's not quite proportional?) but makes higher orders unlikely.

Comment: @me10240 The turbulent regime is characterized by $Re>>1$. As $Re$ is the ratio of the inertial forces to viscous forces, the turbulent regime is dominated by inertial forces rather than viscous forces and it is independent of viscosity. This is reflected in the fact that $C_d$ becomes a constant value in the turbulent regime. Then viscosity no longer has any role in the quadratic drag relation.

Comment: @ChrisDrost you are right that the form is loosely derivable from a momentum balance. I have edited the answer.

Comment: @ChrisDrost: I understand the form you derived. But I am still confused how to show that the mathematical formula for drag as the integral of the traction  implies this result. Could you write down a short derivation, if it is possible to derive it from that starting point?

Comment: Yes, but you're not necessarily going to like it: use the reference frame where the fluid flow is constant and the Bernoulli's principle expression for pressure, with the understanding that in this flow regime you're going to be dragging some sort of fluid behind you at speed $v$. Bernoulli's principle says that the fluid behind you therefore is going to be at some pressure $p - \frac{1}{2}~\rho~v^2$ which when you integrate it gives some dimensionless parameter $C_d$ depending on what exactly the flow is otherwise doing while it follows you.

Comment: That $C_\mathrm{d} \to 1$ as $\mathrm{Re} \to \infty$ is no surprise, since we are then in the ballistic regime and the fluid can be modeled as a collection of non-self-interacting particles reflecting off the object.

Comment: @ChrisDrost : I see why you said I wont like it. The derivation is appropriate when Bernoulli's equation holds---so we need, steady, irrotational, incompressible flow. Steady and incompressible are fine, but irrotational is not always true. So am I right when I say the quadratic drag formula  is a crude heuristic rather than a formal expression from first principles ?

Comment: @me10240 What a great student! Yep, when the Reynolds number gets to be about $10^6$ the drag coefficient abruptly drops. But you don't have to dismiss it as a "crude heuristic" if you don't want to: you can take it as 100% always true, and then [plot the function](http://web2.clarkson.edu/projects/crcd/me637/notes/aerosols/aerosols_page3.html) $C_d(\text{Re})$, showing the linear drag $\text{Re}<1$, the $v^2$ regime $1000<\text{Re}<250,000$, and the sudden "rotational" change when vortices start being shed at $\text{Re} > 300,000.$ Professional physicists tend to do the latter, I think.