# Can we derive Stokes' drag law from Navier-Stokes' equation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, viscosity, navier-stokes

So basically [Stokes' law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_law) states that,

> "The drag force on a spherical body of radius $r$ and velocity $v$ is
> $$F_{d}=6\pi \eta rv.$$

**My question:**

$(1)$ Can we derive Stokes' drag law from Navier-Stokes' equation?

Comment: Closely related/possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/197259/226902 "How does the mathematical definition of drag reduce to Stokes or form drag?",  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235507/226902 "Basis for Derivation of Stokes Friction Law for Spheres", https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/537455/226902 "Deriving Stokes' law in a simple way"

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can find a [derivation](https://archive.org/details/landau-and-lifshitz-physics-textbooks-series/Vol%206%20-%20Landau%2C%20Lifshitz%20-%20Fluid%20mechanics%20%282nd%20ed%2C%201987%29/page/61/mode/1up) in Landau and Lifshitz' textbook on Fluid mechanics in the Section on [Flow with small Reynolds numbers](https://archive.org/details/landau-and-lifshitz-physics-textbooks-series/Vol%206%20-%20Landau%2C%20Lifshitz%20-%20Fluid%20mechanics%20%282nd%20ed%2C%201987%29/page/58/mode/1up) in the Chapter on viscous fluids. The calculation is rather involved. Note that this is true only in the limit of a vanishing Reynold's number, the general calculation cannot be done analytically.

Hope this helps and tell me is you need more details.