# How to mathematically derive the pressure contribution to drag force over a sphere after the viscous stress is determined?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, differential-equations, viscosity, navier-stokes

I've looked in a lot of books on how it would be possible to derive the drag force over a sphere using PDEs. I've also learned in my fluid dynamics class how to derive the drag force of a rotating sphere in steady flow but we didn't use PDEs. Instead, we used superposition and potential flow to find a solution.

I've been able to derive half of the problem mathematically determining that $F_D$ is $4\pi\mu UR^2$ but I can't derive the pressure contribution as substituting my $\frac{\delta u}{\delta r}$ into stokes law results in the pressure contribution being equivalent to zero.

Comment: duplicate: [Can we derive Stokes' drag law from Navier-Stokes' equation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/713384/333454) with links to other similar questions in Quillo's comment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deriving Stokes' law ($f_v=6\pi\eta Rv$) in a simple way](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/537455/)

Comment: Stoke's law is for creeping flow in which the stream function satisfies the biharmonic equation.